# Initialize text input fields in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which shows input fields and I want to initialize those fields with data from the server. The problem is that I can't do that while using ng-model. 
Before using a directive I used in the controller something like $scope.field1 = $scope.first.field1

Here's my code. I simplified it for the sake of readability but the idea's here.

In my controller I have this code:

```
app.controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData) {
        myData.then(function(data) {
            $scope.first = data.first;
            $scope.second = data.second;
        });
}]);
```

Inside first and second I have 2 field: field1 and field2.

In in html code, I have this bit:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<my-directive info="first"></my-directive>
<h1>Second</h1>
<my-directive info="second"></my-directive>
```

The directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'static/js/myDirective.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.doStuff = function() {
                /* Do stuff with 
                scope.field1 and scope.field2 */
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and the myDirective.html code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myfield1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="myfield2" />
<input type="submit" ng-click="doStuff()" />
```

If in myDirective.html I write:

```
<input type="text" value="info.field1" />
```

I can see the value fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: it is not a single mistake you are doing. you have many of them. read angular directive docs and retry. you misunderstood directive concept and trying to access parent scope variable from your directive which has isolate scope

Comment: Can you tell me where I am trying to access parent scope from the directive?

Comment: in myDirective.html you are trying to access field1 and field2 which doesn't exist on your directive scope

Comment: @bahadir `myDirective.html` is the directive template.

Comment: yes, i can see that. what i am trying to say is, scope of directive doesn't contain field1 and field2. i thought they must be present in controller scope. if scope.doStuff is generating field1 and field2 they still won't be available until button click. thus fields wont be initialized

Comment: @bahadir: field1 and field2 are present. If I use : <input type="text value="info.field2" /> it shows. I think the issue is when I "simplified" the code I wrote it not clear

Comment: If not specified initially, it is `undefined`. In that case, `ng-model` still works.

Comment: oh sorry then @onTheDev i misunderstood your code. for your problem i'll write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your directive initializes before your data loads. and your directive sees ng-model as an undefined variable. You are not using info directly in template so no auto $watch's for you :).

you need to $watch your info variable in directive and call your doStuff function on change.

note: i wouldn't recommend adding a controller to a directive just for this task. adding a controller to a directive is needed when you need to communicate with other directives. not for waiting async data

edit

you should do

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'static/js/myDirective.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doStuff = function() {
            /* Do stuff with 
            scope.field1 and scope.field2 */
        }
        scope.$watch('info', function(newValue){
            scope.doStuff();
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to read a bit more about $watch, but I'll tell you if I solved my issue.

Comment: Actually the doStuff function was just here to show that I want to use the field1&2 at some point. But I did manage to initialize the fields with this code so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdenwj3g/).

Define a controller for the directive and do the initialization inside it:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'myData', function ($scope, myData) {
           myData.then(function(data){
               $scope.first = data.first;
               $scope.second = data.second;
           });
        }],
        ...
    },
```

Comment: By doing the initialization inside inside the controller, do you mean having something like "$scope.first.field1= ..."? (I'm sorry it's the first time I'm using angular)

Comment: I tried actually but it didn't work. I tried with $scope.first.field1= data.first.field1. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Indeed in the jsfiddle it works. I'm not sure why it didn't work when I tried... I did manage to solve my problem with another solution but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the directive, `myfield1` and `myfield2` don't exist. You are close to solving the issue by using `info.field1` instead.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Faking myData here; in your example this would come from the server
var myData = {
    first: {
        field1: "FirstField1",
        field2: "FirstField2"
    },
    second: {
        field1: "SecondField1",
        field2: "SecondField2"
    }
};
  
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.first = myData.first;
    $scope.second = myData.second;
}]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="info.field1" /><input type="text" ng-model="info.field2" /><input type="submit" ng-click="doStuff()" />',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.doStuff = function() {
                alert('Info: ' + scope.info.field1 + ', ' + scope.info.field2);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>First</h1>
    <my-directive info="first"></my-directive>
    <h1>Second</h1>
    <my-directive info="second"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: The funny thing is I wrote something like that at first but somehow I thought I would be able to change the fields' values and access them with the name "info.field1".. It's stupid but I'm just starting to understand angular and get confused a lot on the way..

Comment: @onTheDev No problem, it can be confusing. Don't forget to upvote or accept if this solved your issue.

Comment: bahadir solution did the trick and I can't accept two answers, so upvote it is!